# Magento Multistore SEO Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, seo, multi-website, multidomain

[M1]

I have a magento store and we have different stores for each country. We have 6 websites:

au.mydomain.com 
us.mydomain.com 
uk.mydomain.com 
uae.mydomain.com
    in.mydomain.com
 ca.mydomain.com

Problem is, each website has the same categories, product, and even the content. The only difference is the pricing & currency. I'm quite sure this would create a duplicate content issue and would lessen our chances of ranking on Google. I guess we are already facing the issue because we rank nowhere till 10 pages of Google Search.

What's your best recommendation for SEO in such a case? We would like to rank with different domains in different countries, for example, we want to rank on google.com.au with our au.mydomain.com & on google.co.uk with uk.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is dont do it. You cant have this and not negatively affect SEO.

This is just about the highest profile example of where this has gone wrong

> To stay competitive, the retailer launched 200 versions of its website depending on which country the customer is in, which had a negative effect on ASOS' search engine rankings.

- https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-47877688

Here is an analysis

https://www.finally.agency/blog/the-asos-international-seo-disaster-what-went-wrong

> Handling a large number of regional domains is always going to be difficult and comes with an inherent risk to SEO performance. If you don’t have the correct relationships (via tagging and international SEO support) set up on your website for international search, you’re vulnerable to content duplication issues and are more than likely going to end up with poor regional targeting. You don’t want a German user to land on a beautifully localised French language domain and vice versa.

Which is why I questioned when SEO consultants I've dealt with started pushing 'localised content' in the form of pre selected currency and pricing and similar setup to handle minor differences in English (en-us vs en-gb) for example.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you will gain a lot more if you hire a professional marketing manager. who will be engaged in advertising and promotion in social networks, developing an effective advertising campaign, PPC, affiliates, discounts, cashback, sales.

do not rely on traffic from search engines - this is a dead end.

even if you double your text and index value will grow eventually, one day search engines will shift, rotate keywords weight, this is why search is always going up and down.

permanent backlinks, social network integrations, google adwords, tv ads - will give you much steady gain.

another issue, you dont have to build multi-region domains, while you can differentiate regions by currency and delivery options.